# DFL parameter in Firebase Dynamic Links Builder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I need to programmatically build a dynamic link using the Dynamic Link Builder API on Android (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create). This is the only option applicable for my case since I need to track click data and shorten links.

This link can be opened on the desktop, but the problem is that the link will be eligible only for mobile apps - the website is unable to recognize this link (this behavior is intentional). I would like the desktop user is directed to the website's main page.

Here is the quote from Firebase doc:

> When users open a Dynamic Link on a desktop web browser, they will load this URL (unless param dfl is specified). If you don't have a web equivalent to the linked content, the URL doesn't need to point to a valid web resource. In this situation, you should set up a redirect from this URL to, for example, your home page.

I see I need **dfl** parameter. (**dfl is The link to open on desktop, overriding param link.**) How can I specify **dfl** parameter using Dynamic Links Builder on Android?

I know that I can specify **dfl** by building dynamic link manually -   https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
But this approach is not useful for me since it has such constraints:

> If you don't need to track click data in the Firebase console and you don't care if the links are long...

Does anybody know the right solution or some trick to achieve this? Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, that simple appending does work...

When the builder composes the Uri, I append it with &dfl=XXXXX

When I try to open this link on browser PC it directs me to URL in **dfl** parameter, but on the device, it opens Play Store or app (if it's installed).

The absence of such method confused me, but the solution is found.

Comment: Yep, that should work. I can confirm the parameter doesn't have a setter currently in the Android api.

Comment: You can use the [setLongLink function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create#shorten-a-long-dynamic-link)

Comment: Hi Alexandr, I try your approach but I am not getting the result as expected, could you post the final link you use?

Comment: @Juanje I checked out their documentation. It seems that the parameter name has been changed: dfl -> ofl

Take a look: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually
Let me know if it helps.

I had something like this:
` String longDynamicLink = "https://jasid384234.app.goo.gl/" +
                "?apn=android.app.id" +
                "&ibi=ios.bundle.id" +
                "&link=" +  urlEncodedRefLink +
                "&dfl=" + URLEncoder.encode(dflLink, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrKarpovich, I will try to make it manually because I am appending this parameter to the default link generated with the provided methods and still don't work. The link I want to show is the Play store link, the default behaviour but also in the desktop browsers.